# Read large CSV, replace some column values from oracle db and write new csv

Tags: c#, oracle, parsing, csv

I have large csv files (from 2GB up to 25GB) which are different structe. I've made a c# app where user enters position of the columns he wants to replace. Now I have to read the csv, compare the columns from csv to columns that are stored in oracle db table, replace the columns from csv if the select conditon is met, and store the result in new csv.

Now the questions are: what is the best and fastest way to do this? What is the best way to access the db only once to do the select statement for column comparissment and not for every csv line?

Now I've used StreamReader for reading and then spliting csv lines, but I don't know what would be the best way to compare it to the values in db?

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StreamReader is an easy way which propably also is not that fast.

If you're able to detect the line number without iterating over all lines you may try with MemoryMappedFiles (might also work with streams if they support seeking)

Then jump into the middle of the file and check if you're above or below the desired line. 
Then jump to the middle of the remaining half (upper if hit value is below / lower if hit value is above) and repeat.

This converges with a few iterations even on quite large files.